# Can anyone help how to solve this issue of Firebase setup in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, build.gradle

Performing hot restart...

Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...

Restarted application in 2,277ms.

E/flutter ( 7531): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

E/flutter ( 7531): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:210:7)

E/flutter ( 7531): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 7531): #1      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:29:44)

E/flutter ( 7531): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 7531): #2      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:7)

E/flutter ( 7531): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 7531): #3      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)

E/flutter ( 7531): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 7531): #4      main (package:firebasetesting/main.dart:7:3)

E/flutter ( 7531): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 7531):

I am trying to set up the Firebase for Flutter app, I followed all the required steps however I am getting this strange error.

Answer (score 1):

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: const FirebaseOptions(
apiKey: "api key here",
appId: "app id here",
messagingSenderId: "messaging id",
projectId: "project id here",
),
```

Try this. It might work. I was using flutter 3.10.5 and it was working than I upgraded to flutter 3.13.7 and got the same error. I did this and the issue was resolved

Comment: How can I find these values in the Android Studio?

Comment: @SamievGhayrat You can find these values in the json file downloaded while creating a project on firebase console

Comment: Hi, I was stuck with this problem for a couple of days. thank you so much for your answer. The app is working perfectly